# mpz_powm with gmp why it returns 1?

Tags: c++, algorithm, gmp

I have the following code and the problem is that the result is 1. The 3 numbers are generated with an algorithm but it should have a very small probability that the result of that is 1 (look at that n - 256 bits long).

```
int main()
{
   mpz_t a, b, c, result;


   mpz_init(a);
   mpz_init(b);
   mpz_init(c);
   mpz_init(result);

   mpz_init_set_str(a,  "f1231212317f905af25ca06aa2234b2ff1231212317f905af25ca06aa2234b30", 16);
   mpz_init_set_str(b, "94ae1752817e4c42124c0aee0682fbdb08963cdf94434e42fa7f813d888c02", 16);
   mpz_init_set_str(c,     "4a570ba940bf26210926057703417df32874c857872d4cae532af37a8bcd959", 16);


   printf("\n\n%s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, a));
   printf("\n\n%s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, b));
   printf("\n\n%s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, c));

   mpz_powm(result, a, b, c);

   // result = (a ^ b) % n - why is 1 ?!?!

   printf("\n\n%s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, result));
   printf("\n   done");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless, of course, it is an algorithm intended to produce numbers that give `1` here.... Aside: you should have used `mpz_set_str` rather than `mpz_init_set_str`, because you've already initialized those variables. (alternatively, omit the `mpz_init` calls for them)

Comment: The result is really 1, it´s no error in GMP. (I checked with independent code, but it´s a bit long to post)

Comment: My program surely don´t use GMP, because it´s a Bigint class I wrote from scratch (with some calculation stuff for it too), without any additional lib (some time ago, mostly for fun :p). But you shouldn´t make an "answer" with a status update. Answers on SO are meant for full answers. Use comments, or edit your question (depending on the case)